# Access GOTO with other class in vb

Tags: vb.net, goto

How can i access goto with other class. the first code as my first class and the bottom code was my second class. i want to execute that line of class1 using goto by the second class.Heres my code maybe someone will understand what i mean.

> Class1

```
Next4sides:  'My label here
        'MsgBox(ObjectFunction.count)
        If ObjectFunction.count = 1 Then
            Me.Size = New Size(506, 200)
            CreateObject.AddTextBox()
            CreateObject.AddLabel()

            CreateObject.lbl.Text = "Square"

            CreateObject.txtbox.Text = "Enter length side"
            CreateObject.txtbox.Name = "txtlengthside"

            cmbox.Visible = False


        ElseIf ObjectFunction.count = 2 Then

            CreateObject.AddTextBox()
            CreateObject.AddTwoTextBox()

            CreateObject.lbl.Text = "Rectangle"

            CreateObject.txtbox.Text = "Enter width"
            CreateObject.txtbox.Name = "txtrecwidth"

            CreateObject.txtbox1.Text = "Enter height"
            CreateObject.txtbox1.Name = "txtrecheight"

        End If
```

> I want to access the label "Next4sides:" from this class2

```
 If count = 1 Then
            If (String.Compare(CType(Form1.Controls("txtlengthside"), TextBox).Text, "return", True) <> 0) Then
                If e.KeyChar.Equals(Microsoft.VisualBasic.ChrW(Keys.Return)) Then
                    Shape.setSquare(CType(Form1.Controls("txtlengthside"), TextBox).Text)
                    MsgBox("Type Return In The Box to Return to main menu" & vbNewLine & vbNewLine & "Answer" & vbNewLine & "Area: " & Shape.getTriangle() & vbNewLine & vbNewLine & "Next is Rectangle")
                    count = count + 1
                    CreateObject.txtbox.Dispose()
     'FROM THIS LINE I WANT TO ACCESS THE LABEL USING GoTo
                End If
            Else
                Application.Restart()
            End If
```

Comment: First thing you should do is decide which language you are using.  VB.NET is not VBA and neither of them is VB6

Comment: 1) Goto is usually a considered bad practice and your case does not seems to be an exception. 2) labels are local to a single method so you can't `GoTo` another class no matter how hard you try.

Comment: Sorry i thought that vba,vb6 and vb.net were just the same...i am using visual studio 2010 visual basic.

Comment: If it is indeed VB.NET, then 1980's era `GoTo` (and the resulting [Spaghetti Code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spaghetti_code)) really has no place in OOP, classes etc.  Its the 21st Century.  Join us. (All the main tags include text to provide guidance on when a tag applies or does not).

Comment: is there anything i could try just to repeat the if else statement without using a loop because my program logging and i cant input values to my textboxes

Comment: If you are trying to `GoTo` another class, then that means that there should be either a member function in the target class or a common shared function called by both classes.

Comment: Just put you code in `class 1` in a public `function` or `sub` and then call it from `class 2`.

Comment: I got it guys..Thanks so much...i just call an event method from class 1 to class 2 just to repeat my if else command.

Comment: An 'event method' *should* be private to the class that owns it and events should not be invoked directly

Comment: It's sad that GOTO is verboten. Unconditional jumps are a necessary part of  computer programming. People just hide their GOTOs e.g. Loops that don't loop (Exit Do = hidden GOTO); Methods that are only called once (Exit Sub = hidden GOTO), Unnecessary exception throwing (Throw Exception = hidden GOTO) etc. 

Properly used, GOTO can result in concise, clear code. But using GOTO is instantly seen as bad programming.

Comment: If you want to be able to run that piece of code in Class 1, make it a Sub or Function and call it.